# Where can I find a good online fundamental data provider for Hong Kong stocks?

Tags: stocks, investing, online-data-source, market-data, hong-kong

I am thinking of investing in the Hong Kong stock market. One problem I am facing is finding a good online fundamental data provider that provides a database of financial statements for Hong Kong stocks. It should provide the user with an interface to easily extract the financial data of the company. I do not mind paying but something as expensive as Bloomberg Terminal is surely beyond me.

If someone is using such a service, please share your experience. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you check out [China Stock Markets Web](http://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/csm/homepage.asp?LangCode=en) provides details on all things that trade on there. It covers the Hang Seng Index, SSE Index, and SSE Component Index.

There is also tons of information for investors on the exchange website [here](https://www.hkex.com.hk/eng/global/investors.htm).

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for some sort of software that provides the user with an interface to easily extract the financial data of the company.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [WorldCap.org](http://worldcap.org). They provide fundamental data for Hong Kong stocks in combination with an iPad app. *Disclosure: I am affiliated with WorldCap.*